# Virtualenv for project started giving error for sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, virtualenv

I created vritualenv for my project A. I ran the same project A after long time.

I was using same virtualenv for other projects as well ,so depending upon other requirements I have installed other libraries as well.

Now when I running project It gives me `sklearn`, which was working fine earlier.

What can be the reason now it gives import error with sklearn package?

[image]

Comment: As a general rule a virtual environment shouldn't be shared between projects.  That's the entire point of virtual environments.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the code after a long time, I suspect your old code is outdated.

You can actually use `import joblib` directly instead of doing it using `sklearn.externals`, since it is deprecated in the latest version of scikitlearn.

> DeprecationWarning: sklearn.externals.joblib is deprecated in 0.21 and will be removed in 0.23. Please import this functionality directly from joblib, which can be installed with: pip install joblib.

You might want to run this first:

```
pip install joblib
```